# Import multi HTML files into One Sheet in Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I've never coded in VBA so this might seem pretty basic but I still can't find any answer anywhere.

So, I have a folder with many HTML files, I want to import all of them into a worksheet in Excel.

I tried this code that I took from another post, but this code imports only one HTML file:

```
Sub Open_HTML_Save_XLSX()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:\LimitsChanges\Alerts.htm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End Sub
```

**Now my question is:** How can I import all the HTML files in that folder into one worksheet in Excel?   With a loop maybe?

**Formatting:** Each HTML should be added **under** (not at the right of) the previous HTML in the worksheet, so I can have certain number of columns and indefinite number of rows depending of the quantity of HTML files.

Comment: Just reasoning about this problem may give you some pointers. Open a single file and `SaveAs` obviously won't cut it. In essence you want you create a workbook and append content to it. Assuming that Excel does some transformation of html when saving it (I simply don't know), a way forward could be to open a workbook, open and save the html file in a separate, temporary excel file, read the content of that and append it after the last row of your workbook, delete temp file, process next html file, and so on. That obviously doesn't answer your question but may help you conceptually.

Comment: If the html files are all in the same format (you didn't specify), and you are using them like a 'database', a different approach could be open the html files as some textstream one by one and parse them..

Comment: @ArnovanBoven Exacty what I mean, append each file after the last row of the previous file in the workbook.  But I have 100+ HTML files, applying your method takes a lot of time and trivial work, doesn't it?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more information, but I suppose it is safe to assume that it may take a few minutes.

Comment: And you need lots of html files as html code in one file ... Because? I' m not sure if you know what your few lines of VBA are doing.